# Mouse Controls Android Screen

Tags: android, eclipse, mouse, mouseevent

I would like to use a mouse-like device to control a cursor on the android screen and I have looked into various ways of doing this but none are able to control other applications and be run from an android project, so I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I looked into MonkeyRunner and ChimpChat and I am able to control an android tablet from my laptop through ChimpChat but I am confused as to whether this would work beyond accessing the tablet directly from my laptop because it seems like this would create a security hole. I am also unable to use ChimpChat from an Android Application in Eclipse and can only use it in a java project so any tips on using MonkeyRunner or ChimpChat in an android project on eclipse would be appreciated.

I also looked at using MouseEvents but I wasn't sure if they could communicate with applications other than my own and I looked at using a .sh file to convey mouse clicking and dragging but I wasn't sure how exactly to go about this so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello i had similar problem here -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/9925367/1075066

Comment: sorry but I don't really see how that applies to my question. Maybe I should have been more specific. The error I was getting was noClassDefFoundException for com.android.chimpchat.Chimpchat if that helps a little more. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use MonkeyRunner or ChimpChat from an Android application. MonkeyRunner and ChimpChat are designed to run test cases on a device from an external computer.